# Reference writes "pages" instead of "pp"

Tags: bibtex

I have the following reference in the bib file.

```
@inproceedings{pour2016clustering,
  author="Pour, Shahrzad M. and Benlic, Una",
  editor="Madureira, Ana Maria and Abraham, Ajith and Gamboa, Dorabela and Novais, Paulo",
  title="Clustering of Maintenance Tasks for the {D}anish Railway System",
  booktitle="Intelligent Systems Design and Applications",
  year="2017",
  publisher="Springer International Publishing",
  address="Cham",
  pages="791--799"
}
```

When I add this in my document with `\bibliographystyle{apa}\biboptions{authoryear}`, it gives me this output. 
[image]

However, what I want is

> Pour, S. M. and Benlic, U. (2017). Clustering of maintenance tasks for the Danish railway system. In Madureira, A. M., Abraham, A., Gamboa, D., and Novais, P., editors, Intelligent Systems Design and Applications (pp. 791–799) Cham: Springer International Publishing.

I want to change pages to pp and put it in parenthesis. There is also colon after the city.

Only books and proceedings do not follow the necessary format. Articles are in the correct format with APA style.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using natbib or biblatex?

Comment: @EdL - Given that the code features the instruction `\biboptions{authoryear}`, odds are that the OP uses the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: It's an elsarticle. We're using whatever's embedded in elsarticle and not adding any additional package. Possibly natbib.

Comment: @ADoe - The `elsarticle` document class loads the `natbib` package *automatically*.

Comment: This is more to do with the bst file you are using. It is using a `n.dashify` function to put dashes between them. As with `\bibliographystyle{apa}` it means you're using the `apa.bst` which seems to have no mention of `pp` anywhere.